# favicon will not show up after I point my noip to my domain name

Tags: php, favicon

My favicon will not show up on three different web browsers opera, Firefox, and Chrome and I have cleared cookies and cache so it’s not that. This started happening after I pointed my noip  my domain name. What did I do wrong? How can I fix it?
http://404tool.dns.net has the favicon
http://404tool.com  favicon is gone

```
<?php
session_start();
include('inc/config.php');
include('inc/functions.php');
BlockIP();
LoggedInTrue();
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>404Tool - Home</title>
<link rel="icon"type="image/ico"href="img/favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css"
media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="sidebar">
    <div id="menu">
        <div id="menu-header">
            <div id="title">
                <span>404</span>Tools
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="menu-account">
            <div id="account-info">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>User</td>
                        <td><span><?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?></span></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Level</td>
                        <td><span>Guest</span></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="menu-menu">
            <div class="menu-news">
                <h2 class="current"><a href="#">Home</a></h2>
            </div>

            <div id="menu-login">
                <ul>
                    <li id="loginstrip"class="current"><a href="#" id="login">Login</a></li>
                    <div id="dropdown">
                        <form method="POST">
                        <div id="dropdown-strip">
                            <div id="dropdown-text">
                                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div id="dropdown-strip">
                            <div id="dropdown-text">
                                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div id="dropdown-strip2">
                            <div id="dropdown-text">
                                <span id="loginbutton"><input type="submit" value="Login" name="login" /></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php Login(); ?>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="main-news">
    <div id="main-header">
        <div id="main-title">
            Home
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="main-content-news">
        This is a Private Service and accounts are created by filling out the form below. Please wait 48 hours for the account to be created before submitting another account request!
    </div>

    <div id="main-content-news">
        <div id="box">
            <br />
            <br />
            <div id="box-header">

            </div>

            <div id="box-content">
                <div id="box-title">

                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="box-content">
```

Comment: Is it just me who finds it ironic that you're building a site called '404 Tools' and you're asking for help with a 404 error?

Answer (score 0):

It currently looks like you are serving different version of the app. Look at the source code from each of those sites and you'll see that 404tools.com does not have a favicon link in the `<head>...</head>`

http://404tools.ddns.net/:

```
<head>
    <title>404Tools - Home</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="img/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
</head>
```

http://404tools.com/

```
<head>
<title>404 tools</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="email bomber, skype resolver, skype, 404, tools, sms bomber, geo location, ip logger,">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<style type="text/css"></style>
</head>
```

Comment: I see I used 1and1.com to get my domain name.. how would I go about fixing this??

Comment: I'm not sure it has anything to do with who you registered the name with - more like your hosting provider. Try making changes and uploading them, then check that both domains get the update.

Comment: OK I'll do that and I'm self hosting it of a raspberry pi

Comment: If you're able to access the logs on the RPi check that both requests are showing up in the logs. Otherwise, it might be something like a VirtualHost config.

Comment: @j.doe if you found this answer helpful, please mark it as accepted by clicking on the green checkmark icon.